# jQuery load does not work on IE 9 ( works fine on FF, Chrome and Safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

This is my site, [http://www.eboard.jp](http://www.eboard.jp/),using Django.
On top page, jQuery "load" on my page  dose not work on IE9, 
though works fine on other browsers. 

Any suggestions about this issue?

This is related JS file and the base html.
http://www.eboard.jp/static/js/main.js

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td id="center">
   <table class="course_filter">
   <tr>
  <td class="search_mes">
   <ul class="intro_list">
    <li>eboard[いーぼーど]は、<br>小学生～高校生の無料学習サイト。</li>
    <li>動画が集まった「コース」を使って、<br>自分のペースで学習を進められます。</li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="link_list">
    <li class=""><img alt="" class="i_18" src="/static/icons/video.png"/>
     <a href="/courses/{{ beginner.id }}/1">動画で学ぼう！ eboardの使い方</a></li>
    <li><img alt="" class="i_18" src="/static/icons/key.png"/>
     <a href="/accounts/signup/">ユーザー登録</a></li>
   </ul>
  </td>

  <td class="filters">
   <ul class="ages">
    <li><a id="ele" class="ele" href="/age=ele/sub=all/"></a></li>
    <li><a id="jun" class="jun" href="/age=jun/sub=all/"></a></li>
    <li><a id="hig" class="hig" href="/age=hig/sub=all/"></a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="subjects">
    <li><a id="mat" class="mat" href="/age=all/sub=mat/"></a>算数・数学</li>
    <li><a id="soc" class="soc" href="/age=all/sub=soc/"></a>社会</li>
    <li><a id="sci" class="sci" href="/age=all/sub=sci/"></a>理科</li>
    <li><a id="eng" class="eng" href="/age=all/sub=eng/"></a>英語</li>
   </ul>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<div id="course_tb">
 <p class="loading"><img alt="" src="/static/images/loading2.gif">
</div>
```

This one is loaded html.

```
<div id="course_tb">
{% paginate 12 popnote_courses %}
{% for course in popnote_courses %}
{% score_for_object course as score %}
 <table class="course c_desc" title="{{ course.title }}|{{ course.description|linebreaksbr }}">
  <tr>
   <td class="thumb">
    <a href="/courses/{{ course.id }}/1"><img alt="{{ course.title }}" class="l_thumb" src="{{ course.thumb }}" /></a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="course_info">
    <ul>
     <li class="course_title"><a href="/courses/{{ course.id }}/1">{{ course.title }}</a></li>
     <li class="course_li">{% for age in course.target_age.all|slice:":2" %}{{ age.layer }} {% endfor %}</li>
     <li class="course_li"><img alt="みんなの評価" class="i_20" src="/static/icons/like.png"> {{ score.score }}
    　<img alt="コース登録者数" class="i_20" src="/static/icons/user.png"> {{ course.reg_count }}人</li>
    </ul>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
{% endfor %}
{% show_more "<img alt="" class="i_24" src="/static/images/loading.gif" > 次のコースを読みこむ" "<div class="loading" ><img alt="" src="/static/images/loading2.gif" ></div>"%}
</div>
```

Comment: when i see it in IE9(Developer tools -> Script Tab) the jquery script seems to be loaded. but the page doesnt render ..   also i get this error..  SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 
www.eboard.jp, line 27 character 3 .seems there is extra ',' on line 26  --> cluetipClass: 'jtip',

Comment: cluetipClass works fine on other pages, so I think this is not the cause. but I'll check it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the network tab in IE, but you'll probably find that it is trying to load the url without the hash on the end.  IE doesn't typically send #tags to the server as they are meant to for client side.

Comment: You're right. I checked with the network tab and fix #tags, that makes it work. Sorry for my late response and thanks!